# How to Pivot Calculations that were converted to Dimensions in Tableau

Tags: pivot, tableau-api, dimension, calculation

I want to make a Pivot on a few Calculation that I turned into Dimensions (TheCalculations are an IF THEN ELSE Construction returning 1 or 0). Now when I go to the Datasource and select thouse Columns i don't get the Option Pivot by presing the Drop Down Arrow. How I need to convert thouse Columns so I can Pivot them?

Thx

Comment: you can't pivot a calculated fields in tableau, If those are fields from database then only you can pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot PIVOT any calculated field. This [feature/idea was suggested in 2015](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4477) when v9 came out but not luck so far.

In their [Tableau Online Help](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.html), it says -

> You can pivot the data in your Microsoft Excel, text file, Google Sheets, and .pdf **data sources**

If you are open to different tool other than Tableau Desktop, take a look at [Tableau Maestro](https://www.tableau.com/project-maestro)

If you are using database as a source, try pivoting there and then using it with Tableau